# How to obtain pxssh module output?

Tags: python, pxssh

I'm trying to use pxssh to send a command.

```
   cmd1 = somecommand
   cmd2 = anothercommand
   cmd3 = cmd1 + cmd2 + hostname
   s.sendline(cmd3) 
   print s.before
```

I need to take only output of my cmd not cmd + output.
s.expect can't help because it cut the output before pattern but i need a messages after.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is a month old, but in case others come here, this should help.

Since the command being sent is on its own line in the output, you could do something like this:

```
output = s.before
output = output.split('\r\n')
output = output[1:]
```